# from which repository can I get latest version of android-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, android-maven-plugin

[maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2/android-maven-plugin) only contains android-maven-plugin up to version 4.0.0-rc.2

where can I get newest version 4.4.3?

Comment: You link is not a link to Maven Central. This will give you the correct result: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|android-maven-plugin which shows version 4.4.3 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this plugin: (same name, but different group id)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.simpligility.maven.plugins/android-maven-plugin